# Cannot set Git Bash as the default terminal in Android studio

Tags: java, android, git, kotlin, android-studio

I am trying to set Git Bash as the default terminal in Android studio in windows, but the file path contains a space character `F:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe`.

For some reason it looks like android studio is inserting a comma in the space which makes the file path obsolete.

[image]

I also tried escaping the space character in several ways, but no luck.
Can someone help me?

Comment: (blind suggestion) have you tried placing double quotes around the string ? `"F:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe"`

Comment: it worked!! I feel so dumb right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place the path inside of double quotes like this:`"F:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe"`